# relational algebra: make symbols pi rho and sigma bigger within an equaiton

Tags: symbols, relsize

Relational algebra notation in database design uses the Greek letters `\sigma` [selection], `\rho` [rename], and `\pi` [projection]. How can I increase the size of these symbols within an equation?

```
\begin{equation}
\pi_{\text{studentId, name, age}}\left(\sigma_{\text{age}\geq36}\left(\text{Student}\right)\right)
\end{equation}
```

The image shows that the sigma and pi are a bit too small especially compared to the word "Student" ...
[image]

Comment: I don't see a problem in their size (BTW: you should not use `\text` here, use `\textup` or `\textnormal`, `\text` will be italic in an italic context). You could make a custom command to make the subscript even smaller.

Comment: Do you maybe want to use the uppercase versions of `\pi` and `\sigma`, i.e.,  `\Pi` and `\Sigma`?

Comment: Hello daleif, I do not really understand the difference between textup textnormal and text. I have replaced text by textnormal and also text by textup but it changes nothing in terms of output.

Comment: @Mico  no I do not want the uppercase version [it's not conventional in database design theory].

Comment: @Swiss12000 as I said, context matters: `\textit{T $\text{T}$ T} vs `T $\text{T}$ T`, your indices should not become italic just because you used your construction inside, say, a theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use the `relsize` package and its `\mathlarger` macro. The following screenshot shows the same equation three times: first with the default sizes of `\pi` and `\sigma`, next with the two symbols enlarged 20%, and finally with the two symbols enlarged 44% (=1.2^2-1). I suspect you may prefer the middle line, i.e., the one with the symbols enlarged by "only" 20%.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize,amsmath} % amsmath for "gather*" env.
%% define \ppi, \ssigma, \pppi, and \sssigma macros:
\newcommand\ppi{{\mathlarger{\pi}}} % 20% enlargement
\newcommand\pppi{{\mathlarger{\ppi}}}
\newcommand\ssigma{{\mathlarger{\sigma}}} % 44% enlargement
\newcommand\sssigma{{\mathlarger{\ssigma}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\pi_{\textup{studentId, name, age}} \left(\sigma_{\textup{age}\geq36} (\textup{Student})\right)\\
\ppi_{\textup{studentId, name, age}} \left(\ssigma_{\textup{age}\geq36} (\textup{Student})\right)\\
\pppi_{\textup{studentId, name, age}} \left(\sssigma_{\textup{age}\geq36} (\textup{Student})\right)
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```